How can I permute pair of elements in a list?
How can I find all permutations (ways of exchanging positions of pairs in brackets) in a list? The position of elements not in pair should not change.
list = {V1, {A1, B1}, {A2, B2}, V2, {A3, B3}, V3};

Some examples of results would be:
{V1, {A1, B1}, {A2, B2}, V2, {A3, B3}, V3}
{V1, {A2, B2}, {A1, B1}, V2, {A3, B3}, V3}
{V1, {A3, B3}, {A2, B2}, V2, {A1, B1}, V3}


permutepairs[list_] := Module[{pairs},
   pairs = ReplaceList[list, {___, {a_, b_}, ___} :> {a, b}];
   (list /. Thread[pairs -> #]) & /@ Permutations[pairs]];

permutepairs[{V1, {A1, B1}, {A2, B2}, V2, {A3, B3}, V3}]


permutepairs[{V1, {A1, B1}, {A2, B2}, V2, {A3, B3}}]



Nice, I spent several hours and couldn't a good way to write it short like this.

res =
  MapAt[Reverse, {All, 2 ;; -1}] @
   (Transpose[{Cases[list, _Symbol], #}] & /@ 
     Permutations[Cases[list, {__}]]);

Join @@@ res // Column



Hi, it works well for the example but if I modified the list a bit like list = {V1, {A1, B1}, {A2, B2}, V2, {A3, B3}}; it does not work on this case.

In this case append V3 with Append[list, V3] and delete it after the calculation of res with res2 = MapAt[Nothing, res, {All, -1, -1}]

An attempt
fn[list_List] := 
 With[{x = Cases[list, {x_, y_}]}, 
  MapApply[Function[Null, Evaluate[Replace[list, 
    Thread[x -> Array[Slot, Length@x]], 2]]]]@Permutations[x, {Length@x}]]

list = {V1, {A1, B1}, {A2, B2}, V2, {A3, B3}, V3};

fn[list]

(* {
     {V1, {A1, B1}, {A2, B2}, V2, {A3, B3}, V3}, 
     {V1, {A1, B1}, {A3, B3}, V2, {A2, B2}, V3}, 
     {V1, {A2, B2}, {A1, B1}, V2, {A3, B3}, V3}, 
     {V1, {A2, B2}, {A3, B3}, V2, {A1, B1}, V3}, 
     {V1, {A3, B3}, {A1, B1}, V2, {A2, B2}, V3}, 
     {V1, {A3, B3}, {A2, B2}, V2, {A1, B1}, V3}
   } *)


list2 = {V1, {A1, B1}, {A2, B2}, V2, {A3, B3}};

fn[list2]

(* {
    {V1, {A1, B1}, {A2, B2}, V2, {A3, B3}}, 
    {V1, {A1, B1}, {A3, B3}, V2, {A2, B2}}, 
    {V1, {A2, B2}, {A1, B1}, V2, {A3, B3}}, 
    {V1, {A2, B2}, {A3, B3}, V2, {A1, B1}}, 
    {V1, {A3, B3}, {A1, B1}, V2, {A2, B2}}, 
    {V1, {A3, B3}, {A2, B2}, V2, {A1, B1}}
}*)


Just for somethinng different:
With[{s = 
   GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[3]] /. 
    Thread[Range[3] -> 
      Flatten[Position[list, _?(Length[#] == 2 &)]]]}, 
 Permute[list, #] & /@ s]


